# CSS vh and dvh used in one statement

Tags: css

I came across this code in a project I am working on and I am not sure if this is a typo or if it is intentional.  Is the idea behind this, that if the browser does not support the dvh option, it would just fallback to the first vh option?   Could someone maybe confirm this and share in which use case this would be needed?

```css
  .container {
    ...
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100dvh;
    ...
  }
```

Comment: yes, you're right. it's a fallback

Comment: See [4.3.8. Unsupported Values](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#unsupported-values) for an example of this pattern in the CSS2 specification.

Answer (score 1):

I'm used to Chrome, Edge, Opera, and Firefox browsers, so they allow these viewport values  **`dvb, dvh, dvi, dvmax, dvmin, dvw`** from the December 2022 Update.

If you want a structured code syntax for unsupported browsers,
You can use [**@supports**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) in your CSS.

```bash
.container{
    max-height:100vh;
}

@supports (max-height: 100dvh) {
  .container{
     max-height:100dvh;
  }   
}
```